# Populate QComboBox with SQL Server in PyQt6

Tags: python, sql-server, pyqt, pyqt6

I want to connect a QComboBox with SQL Server.
I'm creating an employee form, where the user can add the data for each employee. I want to use 3 tables (already made and populated in SQL Server) for the QComboBox, one for the Building, one for the Department and one for the Job. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do it.

I've used some code that I found online, which is the following:

```
self.deptcombbox = QComboBox()
    self.deptcombbox.addItems(self.deptcomb)
```

and

```
def deptcomb(self):
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-QFV3HFM\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Tests;USERNAME=ggs;PASSWORD=2332")
    q = conn.cursor()
    q.execute('SELECT DISTINCT dept_name FROM departments')
    pmList = q.fetchall()
    pmList = list(pmList)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return pmList
```

but I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gnsta\Documents\Programming tests\EmployeeForm.py", line 89, in <module>
    window = Window()
  File "c:\Users\gnsta\Documents\Programming tests\EmployeeForm.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.buildingcombobox.addItems(self.buildcomb)
TypeError: addItems(self, Iterable[str]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'method'
```

I understand that I need to use a list for the combobox, but list() isn't working.

Comment: Using `self.deptcomb` is trying to address a class method as though it were an attribute, a value. Have you tried using `self.deptcomb()` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've changed it to self.deptcomb() and now I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gnsta\Documents\Programming tests\EmployeeForm.py", line 86, in <module>
    window = Window()
  File "c:\Users\gnsta\Documents\Programming tests\EmployeeForm.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.buildingcombobox.addItems(self.buildcomb())
TypeError: index 0 has type 'pyodbc.Row' but 'str' is expected

Comment: `return map(str, pmList)` (or eventually `list(map(str, pmList))`)

Comment: I've changed to both 'return map(str, pmList)' and 'list(map(str, pmList))' and now I get error c:\Users\gnsta\Documents\Programming tests\EmployeeForm.py:63: DeprecationWarning: PyUnicode_FromUnicode(NULL, 
size) is deprecated; use PyUnicode_New() instead
  return list(map(str, pmList)). Note that the data in the SQL are in Greek.